# Javascript converting DateTime to "______ seconds/minutes/hours/months ago"

Tags: javascript, api, datetime, twitter

The Twitter API returns time stamps of the form:

"Sat, 25 Jul 2009 04:54:42 +0000"

What's the best way to convert a time stamp of this form to "________ seconds/minutes/hours/months ago" depending on the time zone?

Thanks

Comment: See this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time)

Answer (score 2):

[Javascript Pretty Date](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/) by John Resig

Answer (score 0):

I do this on my site often but I use PHP not javascript for the conversion